# Finding if a time period overlaps another time period

Tags: mysql, time, sum, overlap

In MySQL is there a way where you can find if two time periods overlaps each other? For instance I want to see if `2015-10-10 9:00:00 - 2015-10-10 15:00:00` overlaps `2015-10-15 12:00:00 - 2015-10-10 18:00:00`. As you can see they do overlap, I was wondering if there's a method for this?

Comment: Consider two lengths of time, a & b. The two periods can be said to overlap if a_start <= b_end and a_end >= b_start

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to know if they overlap or not, you can just check that one range finishes completely before the other one starts.  If this **isn't** the case, there is overlap.

So if you name each timestamp field as start_1 to end_1 and start_2 to end_2, you could use this to select all overlapping records.

```
SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE NOT(end_1 <= start_2 OR end_2 <= start_1)
```

You should also be able to use the same logic expression to create a new result set field.

```
SELECT NOT(end_1 <= start_2 OR end_2 <= start_1) as overlap, * FROM xxx
```